# lucene.net search multiple fields with one value AND other field with another value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, lucene.net

I have a Lucene doc with various fields; Name, BriefData, FullData, ParentIDs (comma delimted string), ProductType, Experience.

I have a search form with a text box, drop down of parents, dropdown of product types, dropdown of experience.

If I search from the text box I get the results I should. If I search from any of dropdowns (or all of them) I get the results I want. If I use the dropdowns AND the textbox I get all results as a search of textbox OR dropdowns. What I want is textbox AND dropdowns.

So, my search builds something like so:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
        {
            searchTerm = "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["textbox"]))
            {
                string tester = Request.QueryString["query"];
                searchTerm += tester;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["parent"]))
            {
                searchTerm += searchTerm.Length > 0 ? " " : "";
                searchTerm += "+ParentIDs:" + Request.QueryString["parent"];
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["product"]))
            {
                ProductTypes pt = db.ProductTypes.Find(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["product"]));
                if (pt != null) {
                    searchTerm += searchTerm.Length > 0 ? " " : "";
                    searchTerm += "+ProductType:" + pt.TypeName;
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["experience"]))
            {
                searchTerm += searchTerm.Length > 0 ? " " : "";
                searchTerm += "+Experience:" + Request.QueryString["experience"];
            }
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(Helper.LuceneSearch._luceneDir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Helper.LuceneSearch._luceneDir);

        _searchResults = string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchField)
                            ? Helper.LuceneSearch.Search(searchTerm).Distinct()
                            : Helper.LuceneSearch.Search(searchTerm, searchField).Distinct();

        return View(_searchResults.Distinct());
```

If I am searching just textbox and dropdown parent I get a searchterm of "north +ParentIDs:62"

What I want is the search to ONLY return results with a parent of 62 AND (Name OR BriefData OR FullData of "north").

I have tried creating a searchTerm of "+(Name:north BriefData:north FullData:north) +ParentIDs:62" and "Name:north BriefData:north FullData:north +ParentIDs:62". The first returns no results and the second returns the same as just searching +ParentIDs:62.

I think the logic behind this is pretty simple. However, I have no idea what it is that I need to write in code.

Please help. :)

Comment: what analyzer are you using? Also are you certain you have indexed data containing "north" in the specified fields?

Comment: I have no idea about analyzers. My search code is as posted.

Comment: I definitely have north indexed. If I search on just north then I get all the results I should from the various fields (Name, BriefData, FullData).

Comment: What I need is to be able to limited the results of searching for north to JUST the ones that have the selected ParentID. And to limit the results of searching for ParentID to JUST the ones that include north in any of Name, BriefData, and FullData fields.

Comment: the code you posted has basically nothing to do with lucene.net, all I can see is code that builds a string to feed the QueryParser, and then its passed into your LuceneSearch helper class

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. All I know is I am building a .Net site and am using Lucene,Net. If all I have given is query syntax then can you help me get that right? Either that or point me in a direction that will help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to JF Beaulac giving me cause to look at the Lucene.Net code I had included (Helper.LuceneSearch.Search(searchTerm).Distinct()) I rewrote my search to essentially not bother using that but instead to somewhat duplicate it.

I did this by using the MultiFieldQueryParser for the, oddly enough, multi-field search I wanted. I then used the TermQuery for single field queries. These were all added to a BooleanQuery and my search was executed against said BooleanQuery.

```
var hits_limit = 1000;
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
{
    searchTerm = "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["textbox"]))
    {
        string tester = Request.QueryString["textbox"];
        var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, new[] { "Name", "BriefData", "FullData" }, analyzer);
        var query = Helper.LuceneSearch.parseQuery(tester.Replace("*", "").Replace("?", ""), parser);
        bq.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["parent"]))
    {
        bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("ParentIDs", Request.QueryString["parent"])), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["product"]))
    {
        ProductTypes pt = db.ProductTypes.Find(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["product"]));
        if (pt != null) {
            bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("ProductType", pt.TypeName)), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["experience"]))
    {
        bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Experience", Request.QueryString["experience"])), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    }
}
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Helper.LuceneSearch._luceneDir))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Helper.LuceneSearch._luceneDir);

var searcher = new IndexSearcher(Helper.LuceneSearch._directory, false);
var hits = searcher.Search(bq, null, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
var results = Helper.LuceneSearch._mapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher).Distinct();
analyzer.Close();
searcher.Close();
searcher.Dispose(); 

return View(results);
```

It should be noted that to get the product and experience fields to work I had to set them to "Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED" when adding them to the index. I'm guessing this was because they would only ever have a single value per document. The other searched fields are "Field.Index.ANALYZED".